# Extending Array in Typescript doesn't allow me to modify array

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a class, that extends `Array`:

```
export class Collection<T> extends Array<T> {
    constructor(items?: Array<T>) {
        super(...items);

        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Object.create(Collection.prototype));
    }

    whereKey(key: string, value: any): T {
        for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if(this[i][key] === value) {
                return this[i];
            }
        }
    }

    removeAt(index: number) {
        this.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

However, using anything standard array method, like `splice()`, or even `filter()`, doesn't work. I get `ImportsHomeComponent.html:15 ERROR TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object` as an error. Literally the only method I can use is push.

I have created the collection like so:

```
getImportTests(): Observable<Collection<ImportTest>> {
    return this.http.get<Collection<IImportTest>>(route('imports/import-tests')).map((importTests: Collection<IImportTest>) => {
        return new Collection<ImportTest>(importTests.map((importTest: IImportTest) => {
            return new ImportTest(importTest);
        }));
    });
}
```

And then tried to remove an element like so:

```
this.importTests.removeAt(this.importTests.indexOf(importTest));
```

I only really need to use a collection but of the `whereKey` method, but I'm open to anything as this is driving me crazy.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to achieve with this collection. Wouldn't array's `find` work as well?

Answer (score 1):

The `Collection` constructor does not call the super `Array` constructor properly. Notice the structure is different:

```
new Collection(["a", "b"]) =>
    Array(2)0: "a"1: "b"length: 2__proto__: Collection

new Array(["a", "b"]) =>
    Array(1)0: (2) ["a", "b"]length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

Try this:

```
constructor(...items) {
        super(...items);

        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Object.create(Collection.prototype));
    }
```